# Data structure to store key - value pair where the value can be modified in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I want to have a data structure where corresponding to each key I have a value(`Int`) associated where the value can be modified like some value can be added to it.

Can `NSMutableDictionary` work ?

If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use NSMutableDictionary to modified values. But for the value, it should be NSNumber. I think like this it will be okay for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store primitive types with Cocoa types like NSMutableDictionary, you need to bridge them to their NS types i.e, NSNumber etc

```
NSNumber *val1= [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
NSNumber *val2= [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *val3= [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict["yourKey"] = val1;
dict["yourKey1"] = val2;
dict["yourKey2"] = val3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42] forKey:@"key1"];

int myNumber = [[dict objectForKey:@"key1"] intValue];
myNumber = myNumber + 10;

dict[@"key1"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

The output of the given code is:

```
{
    key1 = 52;
}
```